# MySQL - Total activity time selection from log table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have users `connection/disconnection` log table:

```
id   user_id  timestamp         action 
1    8        2017-05-01 10:25  connect
2    8        2017-05-01 11:00  disconnect
3    8        2017-05-01 12:10  connect
3    15       2017-05-01 12:11  connect
3    8        2017-05-01 12:10  disconnect
```

**My question is who can I select user_id:8 activity time in hours during on day e.g. `2017-05-01`?**

I have tried to select `connections` from users and `left join` users where `disconnect` time is bigger then connect time and keep first row

```
SELECT u.*,u2.* FROM `user_log` as u 
INNER JOIN  `user_log` as u2 ON u2.action = 'disconnect' 
AND u.user_id =   u2.user_id AND u.`timestamp` < u2.`timestamp`
WHERE u.action = 'connect'
GROUP BY u.id
```

Seems it working but I'm not sure if it is the best approach, also there is case which is not covered when user connected `05-01` but disconnected `05-02` so it mean I have to count till `05-01` 12:00 o'clock

Comment: We use table structure as `id | user_id | timestamp_login | timestamp_logout` - in logout is `null` while user is logged in. I mean it isn't a bad approach.

Comment: @panther thanks for replay. But the problem is that user can do many oter actions during connect and disconnect period that is why this table structure is needed

Comment: ah, didn't know it... We use this table structure just to log user login/logout, from your example it seems to be the same.

Comment: @Armen can you confirm there will be consecutive rows for user like for each connect there will be a disconnect right after connect row ? Or there can be missing rows?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid no there will be for sure diconnect record but can be on next day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @shA.t and others comment posters

**i finally found answer for this question !**

```
SELECT *, sum(timestampdiff(minute,`connect_timestamp`,`disconnect_timestamp`)) `totalMinutes` 
FROM (

    SELECT user_id, LEAST(start_date, second_date) AS connect_timestamp, GREATEST(start_date, second_date) AS disconnect_timestamp 
    FROM (

          SELECT l.id, l.user_id,`l`.`timestamp` AS start_date,
          (CASE
              WHEN l.action = 'connect' THEN (
                  coalesce( 

                     (select `li`.`timestamp`
                      from `logs` as `li` 
                      where `l`.`user_id`= `li`.`user_id`       
                        and `l`.`timestamp` < `li`.`timestamp`  
                        and DATE(`l`.`timestamp`) = DATE(`li`.`timestamp`)
                        and `li`.`action` = 'disconnect'
                      order by `l`.`timestamp`
                      limit 1), 
                      date_add(date_add(date(`l`.`timestamp`), interval 1 day), interval -1 minute)   
                  )
              )
              WHEN l.action = 'disconnect' THEN (
                  coalesce( 

                     (select `li`.`timestamp`
                      from `logs` as `li` 
                      where `l`.`user_id`= `li`.`user_id`       
                        and `l`.`timestamp` > `li`.`timestamp`
                        and DATE(`l`.`timestamp`) = DATE(`li`.`timestamp`)  
                        and `li`.`action` = 'connect'
                      order by `l`.`timestamp`
                      limit 1), 
                      date_add(date(`l`.`timestamp`), interval 0 minute)   
                  )
              )
          END) as second_date
          FROM `logs` as `l` 

   ) as t GROUP BY connect_timestamp

) as t2 GROUP BY user_id, DATE(connect_timestamp)
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1704d/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this query:

```
select `user_id`, `date`
    , sum(timestampdiff(minute,`connectTime`,`disconnectTime`)) `totalMinutes`
from (
    select `l`.`id`, `l`.`user_id`, date(`l`.`timestamp`) as `date` , `l`.`timestamp` as `connectTime`, `l`.`action`
        , coalesce( 
           /* finding first row of disconnect logs after this connect log */
           (select `li`.`timestamp`
            from `logs` as `li` 
            where `l`.`user_id`= `li`.`user_id`       /* user_id should be same */
              and `l`.`timestamp` < `li`.`timestamp`  /* disconnect time should be bigger than connect time */
              and `li`.`action` = 'disconnect'
            order by `l`.`timestamp`
            limit 1), 
            date_add(date_add(date(`l`.`timestamp`), interval 1 day), interval -1 minute)   /* calculate last minute of current date  */
        ) as `disconnectTime`
    from `logs` as `l`
    /* filter connect logs only */
    where `l`.`action` = 'connect') `t`
group by `user_id`, `date`;
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2138a/15)

Comment: thank you, seems this is almost what i'm looking for but there is `scenario` winch is not covered **if user connected today:15 disconnected:16 we weed to see for day 16 report that he was online lets say half of day**

Comment: In that scenario cost of query will hugely grows, I suggest you use an extra way like a scheduler that adds those missed rows. But, I can add another scenario of connecting from 15 till 18 that needs 3 additional rows and so on ... ;).

Comment: @Armen I can also suggest you to add an extra table to store a `calendar` then you can manage it better ;).

Comment: Please can you have a look on this approach: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=9/f2138a/15#!9/072d5/20 . What do you think will be it be possible to remove duplicated rows somehow e.g. `date` compare or some `group by`

Comment: You can use `sum` over absolute value of date differences by `timestampdiff` and add `group by user_id` and ..., But what about your main question: *activity time in hours during on **a day*** ?

Comment: So this is it - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2138a/18 , just sql become littlebit big :) but it works !

Answer (score 0):

```
select con.user_id,SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(dis.timestamp,con.timestamp))))timeinuse 
from(SELECT @a :=@a+1 as line,w.user_id,w.id,w.timestamp ,w.action
 from user_log w ,(select @a:= 0)l
  where    w.action = 'connect' order by w.user_id,w.timestamp)con inner join 
  (SELECT  @b:=@b+1 as line ,w.timestamp,w.user_id
from user_log w  ,(select @b:= 0)l where  w.action = 'disconnect' group by w.id,w.user_id 
order by w.user_id,w.timestamp)dis on con.line = dis.line and con.user_id =dis.user_id group by con.user_id;
```